Index file shown but not the live website
enter image description hereI have deployed my website in the cpanel of namecheap but it shows the following problem in the given image. How can i fix it?
I tried to change the .htacces file but it still did not work, please help me because i cannot fix this porblem by myself.

You did not mention the stack you used to build you app but i guess its django .
For now you're viewing the page through the file manager, so it just outputs the directory content. Now if you are running a django app then you dont just upload your app files into the www folder, it needs to run in a python Virtual environment.
first you need to Setup Python App it should be under ‘Software’ tab  in cpanel, follow the prompt and fill the requested data, some relevant files and folders will be creates and a Virtual environment too. 
this link might be helpful too Steps to setup djago on shared hosting server
